# Get start page and end page number of each bookmark from a pdf in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to extract the name of bookmark and it's child and the inicial page and final page of each bookmark. I have this code, but I can't figure out how i will do it. I wrote the code below, but it doesn't work as spected: I'm using iTextSharp library.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Bookmark
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int StartPageNumber { get; set; }
    public int EndPageNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Bookmark> Kids { get; set; } = new List<Bookmark>();
}

using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

public class PdfBookmarkExtractor
{
    public List<Bookmark> ExtractBookmarks(string filePath)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath))
        {
            IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarksList = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
            int totalPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
            return ExtractBookmarks(bookmarksList, 1, totalPages);
        }
    }

    private List<Bookmark> ExtractBookmarks(IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarksList, int startPage, int endPage)
    {
        List<Bookmark> bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>();

        foreach (var bookmarkDic in bookmarksList)
        {
            Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
            if (bookmarkDic.ContainsKey("Title"))
                bookmark.Title = bookmarkDic["Title"].ToString();
            if (bookmarkDic.ContainsKey("Page"))
                bookmark.StartPageNumber = GetPageNumberFromDestination(bookmarkDic["Page"].ToString());
            if (bookmarkDic.ContainsKey("Kids"))
            {
                int kidsStartPage = bookmark.StartPageNumber;
                int kidsEndPage = (bookmarks.Count > 0) ? bookmarks[bookmarks.Count - 1].StartPageNumber - 1 : endPage;
                bookmark.Kids = ExtractBookmarks(bookmarkDic["Kids"] as IList<Dictionary<string, object>>, kidsStartPage, kidsEndPage);
            }
            bookmarks.Add(bookmark);
        }

        if (bookmarks.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (bookmarks[i + 1].Kids.Count > 0)
                    bookmarks[i].EndPageNumber = bookmarks[i + 1].Kids[0].StartPageNumber - 1;
                else
                    bookmarks[i].EndPageNumber = bookmarks[i + 1].StartPageNumber - 1;
            }
            bookmarks[^1].EndPageNumber = endPage;
        }

        return bookmarks;
    }

    private int GetPageNumberFromDestination(string destination)
    {
        return int.Parse(destination.Split(' ')[0]);
    }

    public void ExportBookmarksToCSV(string filePath, List<Bookmark> bookmarks)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(bookmarks);
            foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
            {
                if (bookmark.Kids.Count > 0)
                {
                    csv.WriteRecords(bookmark.Kids);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I exported the class Bookmark to a csv to debug and it is like this:

```
Title,StartPageNumber,EndPageNumber
"0. COVER PAGE ",0,-1
REVIEW ENDORSEMENT CERTIFICATE,0,2
1.0 INTRODUCTION,3,3
1.1 SUPPLIER INFORMATION,4,5
1.3 - SECTION PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK -,6,6
1.4 MAIN INDEX FOR ALL VOLUMES,7,8
1.8 INDEX OF MANUFACTURERS RECORD BOOK,9,10
2.0 PACKAGE DESCRIPTION(Includes Short Description),11,11
2.1 UNPRICED PURCHASE ORDER,12,25
2.5 MANUFACTURING SPECIFICATIONS & DRAWINGS,26,-1
USYO-CM-VMVMC-GZ-0148_R49A_CS1-Att-Endorsement,2,116
"0. COVER PAGE ",0,1
REVIEW ENDORSEMENT CERTIFICATE,2,-1
1.0 INTRODUCTION,0,-1
1.1 SUPPLIER INFORMATION,0,-1
1.3 - SECTION PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK -,0,-1
1.4 MAIN INDEX FOR ALL VOLUMES,0,-1
1.8 INDEX OF MANUFACTURERS RECORD BOOK,0,-1
2.0 PACKAGE DESCRIPTION(Includes Short Description),0,-1
2.1 UNPRICED PURCHASE ORDER,0,-1
2.5 MANUFACTURING SPECIFICATIONS & DRAWINGS,0,25
```

The final page is set to -1 and the pdf has 116 pages, but USYO-CM-VMVMC-GZ-0148_R49A_CS1-Att-Endorsement,2,116 is starting at second page it is wrong. Please I need to get the start and end of each bookmark.